# Targeting android 12 failed with error of `android:exported`

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12

[after setting android:exported still got this error of Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7iGG.png)After setting all components on Manifest, still receive an error of "Error:
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    package="com.easymountain.quechua">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
<!--        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"-->
<!--            tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />-->
<!--    <uses-permission-->

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


    <application
        android:name=".base.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:installLocation="internalOnly"
        android:label="@string/screen_app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:name,android:hardwareAccelerated,android:allowBackup,android:label">


        <!--        SDKNAVIGATION      -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.easymountain.quechua.ui.sdknavigation.MpMainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE" />

                <data android:scheme="geo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.easymountain.quechua.ui.sdknavigation.navigation.delegate.MpTraceRecorder"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.easymountain.quechua.ui.sdknavigation.poinative.fragment.MpVideoPlayerFullScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/VideoPlayerTheme" />

        <!--        <activity-->
        <!--            android:name="com.onegravity.contactpicker.core.ContactPickerActivity"-->
        <!--            android:enabled="true"-->
        <!--            android:exported="false">-->

        <!--            <intent-filter>-->
        <!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
        <!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->
        <!--            </intent-filter>-->
        <!--        </activity>-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <!--        SDKNAVIGATION -->


        <activity
            android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarSplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.authentification.AuthWebViewActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
             android:configChanges="orientation"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="quechuahikefinder" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="quechuahikefindermobileapplication.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="login"
                    android:scheme="quechuahikefinder" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/mp_google_map_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".ui.utils.gpsStatusListener.GpsLocationReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="com.decathlon.quechuafinder.workmanager-init"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are using some library or implementation that brings this?

Comment: i have set compileSdkVersion to 31 then i setted the components in Manifest with android exported and i still got this error.

Comment: Yes. Quite normal if some library or other implementations brings them in. That is what i said. Manifest files get merged. The result counts.

Comment: shall i upgrade some libraries to solve the issue ?

Comment: I think so. Or use a newer implementation. I would google first if the used library is know for the exported problem. Also first find out which library causes this.

Comment: does not solve the problem yet

Comment: Did you find the library which causes this?

Comment: how can i find it. actually i updated my dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: By not using one.

Comment: not solved the issue

Comment: pls check this link : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#security

Answer (score 1):

For an app targeting Android SDK Version 31(Android 12 OS) or above we need to set the `android:exported="true"` for any of our app's own activity and any 3rd party library's activity in our app's manifest, where ever the `<intent-filter...` is added.

We faced this issue for auth0 Android SDK.